# Python RegEx find and add to beginning

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Just learning RegEx in Python, and got stuck on this case:

```
str = '''
Here are some order bullets:
i. Foo
ii. Bar
iii. Baz
iv. YOLO
...
x. LOL
'''
```

How do I get to this:

```
str = '''
Here are some order bullets:
- i. Foo
- ii. Bar
- iii. Baz
- iv. YOLO
...
- x. LOL
'''
```

Comment: Look into [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex in `MULTILINE` mode:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(?m)^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)', r'- \1', str)

Here are some order bullets:
- i. Foo
- ii. Bar
- iii. Baz
- iv. YOLO
...
- x. LOL
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

**Search:**

- `(?m)`: Enable MULTILINE mode
- `^`: Start
- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)`: Match and group 1+ alphanumeric characters

**Replacement:**

- `-`: Place literal `"- "`
- `\1`: Back-reference to captured group #1

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thx so much

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the nice explanation - I really appreciate it.